# horizontal recycler view with horizontal scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Im learning android and I cant seem to find a way to do this: 
[image: enter imdescription here]

I would like to do the right to left scroll with what I guess would be a recylcer view, but not sure if its this. I just need someone to point me in the right direction.
I guess i would need an interior layout for the recyclerview.

If someone could point me where to figure this out I would be so greatful!

Comment: put your code here.

Comment: Yes you need a recyclerview. Maybe you need a tutorial https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html   https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Step: 1

Create two Model Classes like below.

```
package-name-here;


public class SingleItemModel {


    private String name;
    private String url;
    private String description;


    public SingleItemModel() {
    }

    public SingleItemModel(String name, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }


    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }


}
```

2. Create the other model class SectionDataModel.java

   ```
   package-name-here;;

   import java.util.ArrayList;


   public class SectionDataModel {



   private String headerTitle;
   private ArrayList<SingleItemModel> allItemsInSection;


   public SectionDataModel() {

   }
   public SectionDataModel(String headerTitle, ArrayList<SingleItemModel> allItemsInSection) {
       this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
       this.allItemsInSection = allItemsInSection;
   }



   public String getHeaderTitle() {
       return headerTitle;
   }

   public void setHeaderTitle(String headerTitle) {
       this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
   }

   public ArrayList<SingleItemModel> getAllItemsInSection() {
       return allItemsInSection;
   }

   public void setAllItemsInSection(ArrayList<SingleItemModel> allItemsInSection) {
       this.allItemsInSection = allItemsInSection;
   }


   }
   ```

## 3. Step: 2

Create an Activity with RecyclerView to show the list in vertical order.

```
package-name-here;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.pratap.gplaystore.adapters.RecyclerViewDataAdapter;
import com.pratap.gplaystore.models.SectionDataModel;
import com.pratap.gplaystore.models.SingleItemModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;


    ArrayList<SectionDataModel> allSampleData;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        allSampleData = new ArrayList<SectionDataModel>();

        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle("G PlayStore");

        }


        createDummyData();


        RecyclerView my_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        my_recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerViewDataAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(this, allSampleData);

        my_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        my_recycler_view.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void createDummyData() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            SectionDataModel dm = new SectionDataModel();

            dm.setHeaderTitle("Section " + i);

            ArrayList<SingleItemModel> singleItem = new ArrayList<SingleItemModel>();
            for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
                singleItem.add(new SingleItemModel("Item " + j, "URL " + j));
            }

            dm.setAllItemsInSection(singleItem);

            allSampleData.add(dm);

        }
    }
}
```

- Create an XML Layout for the above activity class

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" />


</LinearLayout>
```

## Step: 3

Now Create an Adapter Class for the recyclerView in the MainActivity.

RecyclerViewDataAdapter.java

```
package-name-here.adapters;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pratap.gplaystore.R;
import com.pratap.gplaystore.models.SectionDataModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList;
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

        final String sectionName = dataList.get(i).getHeaderTitle();

        ArrayList singleSectionItems = dataList.get(i).getAllItemsInSection();

        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(sectionName);

        SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems);

        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);


        itemRowHolder.btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "click event on more, "+sectionName , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        });


       /* Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.bg)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != dataList ? dataList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView itemTitle;

        protected RecyclerView recycler_view_list;

        protected Button btnMore;



        public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.itemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            this.recycler_view_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
            this.btnMore= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMore);


        }

    }

}
```

- Now create an xml Layout file for the above adapter class.

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnMore"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:theme="@style/MyButton"
            android:text="more"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

## Step: 4

Now , In order to make a horizontal RecyclerView , we need create a layout and Adapter class for each row.

list_single_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/android" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/itemImage"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

- Finally, The Adapter Class for Horizontal RecyclerView

SectionListDataAdapter.java

```
package-name-here.adapters;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.pratap.gplaystore.R;
import com.pratap.gplaystore.models.SingleItemModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SectionListDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionListDataAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList;
    private Context mContext;

    public SectionListDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleItemModel> itemsList) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_single_card, null);
        SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

        SingleItemModel singleItem = itemsList.get(i);

        holder.tvTitle.setText(singleItem.getName());


       /* Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.bg)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView tvTitle;

        protected ImageView itemImage;


        public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            this.itemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);


            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), tvTitle.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

> U can implement this kind of layout using recyclerview

When you use a RecyclerView, you need to specify a LayoutManager that is responsible for laying out each item in the view. The LinearLayoutManager allows you to specify an orientation, just like a normal LinearLayout would.

To create a horizontal list with RecyclerView, you might do something like this:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Hope this help u...if u need any help u can ask

Answer (score 3):

Here is quick tutorial for your Horizontal Recyclerview

**XML File**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>
```

**Java Code**

```
RecyclerView recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```