# How to Build Sliding CardView Inside DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-cardview, swipecardview

I'm working on creating `CardView` that are slidable horizontally.

I've been searching on Internet and watching tutorials on YouTube for days. After trying those possible solutions and advice, my app either gets errors I couldn't solve or crashes.

So, here's a screenshot of my app. The two white blank spaces are the `CardView` I'm working on.

[image]

My goal is something similar to the sliding cards in Google Play Store:

[image]

And here's part of my `activity_main.xml`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/jdCampusText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="JD Campus"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/jdCampusCard"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.332" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/jdCampusCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bsCampusText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="BS Campus"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/bsCampusCard"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.657" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/bsCampusCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.884">
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It doesn't need to be `CardView`, anything that's slidable, and can be `onClick` is fine for me.

Comment: You just need to know that the `RecyclerView` can be [horizontal too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460300/how-to-build-a-horizontal-listview-with-recyclerview).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211617/horizontal-recycler-view-with-horizontal-scroll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [horizontal recycler view with horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211617/horizontal-recycler-view-with-horizontal-scroll)